# Immigrated or emigrated?

Tags: discussion

Should questions that migrate into EE be labelled as "immigrated" and should questions that are migrated from EE be labelled "emigrated".

"Migrated" appears to be a label that covers both currently.

Comment: Should we also have "asylum" and "extradited" ?

Comment: I think "extradited" is actually better than emigrated!! Maybe "quarantined" could be used somewhere LOL

Comment: How about "deported" for outgoing?  It has that extra "kicked out" as apposed to just "moved" feel to it.

Comment: Exported or imported is probably less controversial but who cares about controversy. Deported is my new fave but for the other way round maybe imported.

Comment: I suppose deported means sent back to where it came from so maybe that is only allowed to be used as a mark of disrespect to the folk originally sending it to EE.

Comment: Yeah, I see the point about "deported" is back where it came from.  How about "banished" or "excommunicated".  There has got to be a way to say "exported with extreme prejudice" more succinctly.

Comment: Excommunicated works for me and so does evicted. For hitting the disrespect scale hard I think excommunicated is better but, putting my serious head on maybe evicted might be more acceptable and, maybe adopted for the migration in thing.

Comment: @Olin  "Excommunicated" should be used for suspending users.  I wonder, can we put "anathema" to some use?

Comment: @Nick.  Yeah, "anathema" evokes the right feel.  I can go along with Andy's simple "evicted" too.

Answer (score -1):

Distinguishing between migrated in and migrated out is a good idea.  I have been confused in the past when I click on a "migrated" question here, and then suddenly find myself on a different site.

Other times migrated means it came here, but I'm not sure why that's relevant.  Does it really matter when answering a question how it got here?  Answers here should be in the context of this site, regardless of how or why the question is here.  Perhaps we should drop "migrated" altogether.  Such question simply disappear from the original site and appear on the new site.

Let's also keep this in perspective.  Questions get migrated because the OP couldn't be bothered to find the appropriate site, so just blurted it out someplace.  There is no upside in coddling these people along.  Migration should be about what's best for the site(s), not the user experience of some lazy ingrate that we probably don't want around here anyway.

Comment: An *inbound* migrated question doesn't have the [migrated] added to the title.  Inside, it has an automatically generated link to the origin.  An *outbound* migrated question has [migrated] added to the title.  Inside, it has a link to a new location.   (Example: [new home on SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/1002971/awcc-install-alienware-13), [stub on EE.SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/201721/awcc-install-alienware-13).  Stub will be eventually deleted by an automatic clean-up script, although it will remain visible with 10k+ reputation.)

Comment: @NickAlexeev I better look more keenly next time!